# Returning a java List with a scala method

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Can someone help me? I'm trying to port a Java method to Scala but I'm getting a `ClassCastException`.

This is the Java version that works:

```
private static void addCompoundRecipe(String tag, String tagAddon, AspectList creationAspects, int sizeX, int sizeY, int sizeZ, Object... recipe)
{
    List<Object> compoundRecipe = Arrays.asList(new Object[] {creationAspects, Integer.valueOf(sizeX), Integer.valueOf(sizeY), Integer.valueOf(sizeZ), Arrays.asList(recipe)});
    recipelist.put(tag+tagAddon, compoundRecipe);
}
```

`recipelist` is an `HashMap`. When the `compoundRecipe` is retrieved via `recipelist.get("string")` and casted to `List`, all goes fine.

Here comes the troubled conversion:

```
private def addCompoundRecipe(tag: String, tagAddon: String, sizeX: Int, sizeY: Int, sizeZ: Int, aspects: AspectList, recipe: AnyRef*) {
  val compoundRecipe = java.util.Arrays.asList(Array(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, aspects, java.util.Arrays.asList(recipe)))
  if(compoundRecipe.isInstanceOf[java.util.List[_]]) 
    recipes += (tag+tagAddon -> compoundRecipe) 
  else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$tag$tagAddon is not a valid recipe!") 
}
```

Instead of `recipelist`, here I use `recipes`, an immutable `HashMap`.
Of course, when I call it with `recipes.apply("string")`, I have to cast it again to make it fit the method's signature, using `.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[_]]`

The problem is, I get a `ClassCastException` :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to thaumcraft.api.aspects.AspectList
```

Of course I could just write a Java class to do this stuff, but it's become a challenge for me, I really want to get into Scala.

EDIT:
I already pasted line 387, it's `r.get(0)`, and ResearchPage is a simple class which has a Constructor that takes a `java.util.List` paramater, which is what I'm trying to do. There's no need too look more into that, because it's an API and I can't change it, and also because it worked when I wrote my stuff in Java. However, it seems I'm having problems with conversions...here's what I've been trying: `private def addCompoundRecipe(tag: String, tagAddon: String, sizeX: Int, sizeY: Int, sizeZ: Int, aspects: AspectList, recipe: ItemStack*) {

```
val compoundRecipe = (Seq(aspects, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, recipe.toSeq))
if(recipe != null) recipes += (tag+tagAddon -> compoundRecipe) else
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$tag$tagAddon is not a valid recipe!")
```

}

Here's the exception I get now: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.List`
 in the same line 387, of course. So I guess the problem is with implicit conversions?

EDIT: this works:

```
private def addCompoundRecipe(tag: String, tagAddon: String, sizeX: Int, sizeY: Int, sizeZ: Int, aspects: AspectList, recipe: AnyRef*) {

val compoundRecipe = Seq(aspects, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, recipe.asJava)
if(recipe != null) recipes += (tag+tagAddon -> compoundRecipe.asJava) else
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$tag$tagAddon is not a valid recipe!")
```

}

Comment: Can you show more of your code at the point where you are extracting the recipe and attempting to cast it?

Comment: The exception message means that you have an `Object[]` (an array of objects, not a list!) which you are trying to cast to `thaumcraft.api.aspects.AspectList`.

Comment: @Shadowlands: `ResearchPage[] pages` `pages = new ResearchPage[] { new ResearchPage((List) recipelist.get("ThaumicGen"))};` scala version: `pages = Array(new ResearchPage(recipes.apply("ThaumicGen").asInstanceOf[java.util.List[_]]))`

Comment: @Jesper: The thing is, I'm using the `Arrays.asList` method to prevent this very problem...am I missing something?

Comment: @Dr_Benway Please specify which line is producing the class cast exception and what is the full type (include type parameters) to the `recipes` hash map.

Comment: `var recipes = new HashMap[String, Any]()`. You may ask why `Any` instead of `java.util.List[_]`, the reason is this `HashMap` contains various objects. Using an ad hoc `HashMap[String, java.util.List[_]` saves me from casting later but in the end I get the same exception thrown. The exception is thrown by an API method

Comment: @Dr_Benway *Which* api method is throwing the exception? which line?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to thaumcraft.api.aspects.AspectList
 at thaumcraft.client.gui.GuiResearchRecipe.drawCompoundCraftingPage(GuiResearchRecipe.java:387)
 at thaumcraft.client.gui.GuiResearchRecipe.drawPage(GuiResearchRecipe.java:358)
 at thaumcraft.client.gui.GuiResearchRecipe.genResearchBackground(GuiResearchRecipe.java:266)
 at thaumcraft.client.gui.GuiResearchRecipe.drawScreen(GuiResearchRecipe.java:212)`,  http://pastebin.com/vay0YPBf   Line 387 inside `drawCompoundCraftingPage` is `AspectList aspects = (AspectList)r.get(0);` There it casts

Comment: Without the full code is hard to tell without the full scala code... but lets start with here: the `isInstanceOf` call will always evaluate to true, since that is the specified return type of `Arrays.asList`. Also, you're probably better off using this: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$

Comment: So you're suggesting to use a scala Seq and then call `.asJava` ?

Comment: Yes, for that particular issue, but probably not the thing that is causing the actual problem. You'll probably need to post the full scala code for better suggestions.

Comment: Here it comes.. this with the one pasted in the first post is all the scala code  http://pastebin.com/isTS5wd7

Comment: @Dr_Benway Please _edit the question_ with the extra code - its too hard to read large snippets of code in comments (although using pastebin is OK). Also, it now appears that the cast failure is happening in code that _uses_ the created `ReasearchPage` (in the `drawCompoundCraftingPage` method you mention), not directly in the line that creates that instance, as your previous comment would suggest. The relevant line there calls `r.get(0)`, where `r` is the `recipe` field of a `ResearchPage`, so please can we also have the definition of `ResearchPage` so we see what is going into that field?

Comment: Show us line 387 of `GuiResearchReci‌​pe.java`, because that's where the `ClassCastException` originates according to your stacktrace.

Comment: edited main post since it was too long

Comment: @Dr_Benway How are you calling your "almost working" version of `addCompoundRecipe`? Specifically, is recipe coming in as a collection or as multiple arguments?

Comment: @Kyrstellaine nvm, it works now

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there's something wrong with the line `val compoundRecipe = java.util.Arrays.asList(Array(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, aspects, java.util.Arrays.asList(recipe)))`, where you expect to get a `java.util.List[Any]` that contains `sizeX`, `sizeY`... but unfortunately what you get is actually `java.util.List[Array[Any]]` where the inside `Array` contains `sizeX`, `sizeY`... If you pass them on to your java method call, the types won't check.

I don't think it's a good idea to mix java types and scala types within your scala code (e.g. `val compoundRecipe = java.util.Arrays.asList ...`, or `if (compoundRecipe.isInstanceOf[java.util.List[_])`). What seems to be a better practice is to always use scala types in your code, and do the conversion only when necessary (use `.asJava` as @Alvaro suggested).